# Java swing card game error

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

im making a java card game for an assignment and I've struck an issue.

The code below is in different classes.

cgp class.

```
private DisplayableDeck deck = new DisplayableDeck("b1fv.png");
DisplayableCard[] cards = new DisplayableCard[10];
private Thread[] theThreads = new Thread[2];
private int[] players = new int[2];
private Deck D = new Deck();
int count = 0;
Graphics g;

CardGamePanel()
{
    D.buildDeck();
    for(int i=0;i<cards.length;i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int num1 =r.nextInt(52);                       
        cards[i] = new DisplayableCard("1.png",30,30);            
    }
}

 public void go()
{

  if(count < 9 )
  {
      cards[count].display(g); //error here
  }

  count ++;
}
```

simple class extends japplet

```
 private CardGamePanel cgp;
private JButton btnD = new JButton("Flip");
private Thread repaintThread;


public void init()
{
    cgp = new CardGamePanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.add(btnD);
    btnD.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            cgp.go();
        }
    });
    add(cgp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(500,500);
}
```

-

```
public class DisplayableCard extends Card implements Displayable {  
public int x,y;
private Image image;
private String imageFilename = "";

public DisplayableCard(String s,int x,int y) {
    imageFilename = s;
    this.x =x;
    this.y=y;
}

public void display(Graphics g) {
    image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imageFilename)).getImage();
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null); //ERROR HERE
}
```

The game throws the error when i click the button and call the go() method.

Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1"
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DisplayableCard.display(DisplayableCard.java:16)
 at CardGamePanel.go(CardGamePanel.java:31)
 at simple$1.actionPerformed(simple.java:24)
```

Ive wrote where the error appears inside the code.

Not really sure what part is wrong :s Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DisplayableCard.display(DisplayableCard.java:16)
 at CardGamePanel.go(CardGamePanel.java:31)
 at simple$1.actionPerformed(simple.java:24)

Comment: Where do you define count?  I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Where is `g` initialized?

Comment: updated thanks for the responses

Comment: Your display method takes a graphics object, I see you passing "g" to display in go; however, I don't see you ever acquiring a graphics object. You are getting the NPE because g is null. Did you just not show where you are getting a graphics object from? Or are you just not getting one?

Comment: I think that's where my error is occurring then, im not sure what to put in there.

Comment: Are you sure the Exception is occurring at the `drawImage` line and not the one above it? Can you double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get an existing Graphic object. You can get one from JLabel like this:

```
public void init(){
cgp = new CardGamePanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.add(btnD);
btnD.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        cgp.go(panel2.getGraphics());
    }
});
  add(cgp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  setSize(500,500);
}
```

And modify your other method in CardGamePanel class:

```
public void go(Graphic gr){
  if(count < 9 ){
    cards[count].display(gr); 
  }
  count ++;
}
```

But I think it does not help you because you should put your cards in a Top-Level Container or a JComponent which is in the Top-Level Container.
If you would like to know more about this click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#general) this is a tutorial. I hope it helps you to understand.

Comment: Thank you:) Thats cleared that problem. im not sure why its displaying the card barely on the screen though.